# How to delete all users in Firebase auth?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to delete all users I have stored in Firebase auth.

Not sure why there is no "button" in the Firebas console that I can click or select multiple users at the same time. Anyway...

I tried setting up a callable cloud function like this:

```
export const deleteUsers = functions.https.onCall(
    async (req: any, res:any): Promise<any> => {
      const allUsers = await admin.listUsers();
      const allUsersUID = allUsers.users.map((user: { uid: any; }) => user.uid);
      return admin.deleteUsers(allUsersUID).then(() => res.send("deleted"));
    }
  );
```

However, when I try to call it from the `firebase:shell` using `deleteUsers()`, I get the following 400 error:

```
firebase > deleteUsers()
Sent request to function.
firebase > >  {"severity":"WARNING","message":"Request body is missing data."}
>  {"severity":"ERROR","message":"Invalid request, unable to process."}

RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 400, {
  "error": {
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

If I instead call it using `deleteUsers({})` I get the following 500 error:

```
firebase > deleteUsers({})
Sent request to function.
firebase > >  {"verifications":{"app":"MISSING","auth":"MISSING"},"logging.googleapis.com/labels":{"firebase-log-type":"callable-request-verification"},"severity":"INFO","message":"Callable request verification passed"}
>  {"severity":"ERROR","message":"Unhandled error TypeError: res.on is not a function\n    at C:\\Users\\jastr\\Documents\\Company\\chess-marketplace\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\common\\providers\\https.js:365:17\n    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n    at C:\\Users\\jastr\\Documents\\Company\\chess-marketplace\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\common\\providers\\https.js:364:16\n    at newHandler (C:\\Users\\jastr\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\emulator\\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:315:16)\n    at fixedLen (C:\\Users\\jastr\\Documents\\Company\\chess-marketplace\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\providers\\https.js:120:41)\n    at C:\\Users\\jastr\\Documents\\Company\\chess-marketplace\\node_modules\\firebase-functions\\lib\\common\\providers\\https.js:400:32\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n    at async runFunction (C:\\Users\\jastr\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\emulator\\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:547:9)\n    at async runHTTPS (C:\\Users\\jastr\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\emulator\\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:573:5)\n    at async handler (C:\\Users\\jastr\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\emulator\\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:493:17)"}

RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 500, {
  "error": {
    "message": "INTERNAL",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking a **callable** Cloud Function requires that you follow its [protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) or use an [SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function) that implements that protocol.

If you just want to execute your code in a Node script, you can declare it as:

```
export const deleteUsers = function() { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Frank, could you explain how I change my above function?

Comment: If you just want to delete users, you can make a Node.js script  and don't need it to be a Cloud Function. --- If you need it in Cloud Functions however, you will either have to invoke it with an SDK as I linked above, or implement a regular [HTTP handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) and call that with `fetch` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks Frank, however I am still not sure I understand. Let's say I want to execute my code in a Node script and not use Cloud Functions, how do I do that? Can I use the firebase:shell to do it? I guess my question is where I should declare the Node JS function and in what environment/CLI/terminal I run.

Comment: You can setup a new node project anywhere on your machine anywhere on your machine. Wouldn't  have to be a firebase one. Simply add the firebase admin sdk dependency and initialise your app (you will need a service account) and invoke your script with `node myscript.ts`. If you want to avoid having to do that, then convert your existing callable function to a https one that you could invoke from the shell or simply by accessing it in the browser, eg. http://localhost:<your-functions-port>/<projectid>/<regions>/deleteUsers

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Firebase serve and running the HTTP function seems to work, although it seems I have something wrong with my script: `TypeError: admin.listUsers is not a function at deleteUsers`

Comment: That sounds like you may be initializing the Admin SDK wrong. I recommend posting a new question, with the (by now hopefully much simplified) script and without the Cloud Functions tag.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for steering me in the right direction.

I ended up using a library instead https://github.com/siarheidudko/firebase-engine/tree/f053c7e071e95f563b6c1cbde363cdf72f9905a2

It has everything I need. The only thing that worries me is the support of this library. Is there no such library that is officially supported by Google?